# Windows installer ID's

Tags: windows-installer

So, WindowsInstaller takes any ID's for installed packages, example: 673538CFB3FFAAC4380E12843BBFC789 or BA342DECAB7C24D3699041FEA5F66C10 etc. How I can find this ID by known installing package?

Comment: This question seems to be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467429/c-check-installed-programms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample VBScript that pulls various useful properties from any given MSI file without needing to install it. You can manually open a given package using a tool such as [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Alternatively if you are looking to identify currently installed packages, you can iterate installed items using the [Windows Installer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or from the command line using [msiinv.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/07/01/using-msiinv-to-gather-information-about-what-is-installed-on-a-computer.aspx)

```
Option Explicit
Dim argCount:argCount = Wscript.Arguments.Count
Dim sPackageCode, sProductCode, sProductVersion, sDownloadURL, sConfig, sProductName

If (argCount = 0) Then
    WScript.Echo "Usage: msiinfo.vbs <filename>"
    WScript.Quit 1
End If


Dim MSI_FILE : MSI_FILE = Wscript.Arguments(0)

Dim filesys : Set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not filesys.FileExists(MSI_FILE) Then
    WScript.Echo "Unable to find " & MSI_FILE & ", exiting"
    WScript.Quit 1
End If


Dim installer, database, view, result

Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set database = installer.OpenDatabase (MSI_FILE, 0)

Dim sumInfo  : Set sumInfo = installer.SummaryInformation(MSI_FILE, 0)
sPackageCode =  sumInfo.Property(9) ' PID_REVNUMBER = 9, contains the package code.

Dim sDetails : sDetails = "ProductVersion: " & getproperty("ProductVersion") & vbCrLf _ 
            & "ProductCode: " & getproperty("ProductCode") & vbCrLf _
            & "PackageCode: " & sPackageCode & vbCrLf _
            & "ProductName: " & getproperty("ProductName") 

WScript.Echo sDetails

Function getproperty(property)

    Set view = database.OpenView ("SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property='" & property & "'")
    view.Execute
    Set result = view.Fetch
    getproperty = result.StringData(1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use powershell:

```
$winInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
$msiInstalledApps = @()
foreach($item in $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("Products","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, $null)){
    $msiInstalledApps += New-Object PSObject -Property ($hash = [ordered]@{
                Language = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "Language"))
                ProductName = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "ProductName"))
                PackageCode = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "PackageCode"))
                Transforms = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "Transforms"))
                AssignmentType = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "AssignmentType"))
                PackageName = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "PackageName"))
                InstalledProductName = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "InstalledProductName"))
                VersionString = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "VersionString"))
                RegCompany = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "RegCompany"))
                RegOwner = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "RegOwner"))
                ProductID = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "ProductID"))
                ProductIcon = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "ProductIcon"))
                InstallLocation = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "InstallLocation"))
                InstallSource = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "InstallSource"))
                InstallDate = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "InstallDate"))
                Publisher = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "Publisher"))
                LocalPackage = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "LocalPackage"))
                HelpLink = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "HelpLink"))
                HelpTelephone = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "HelpTelephone"))
                URLInfoAbout = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "URLInfoAbout"))
                URLUpdateInfo = $winInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("ProductInfo","GetProperty",$null, $winInstaller, @($item, "URLUpdateInfo"))
                })
}

$msiInstalledApps
```